# How can I label / reference description items that contain macros by name?

Tags: macros, hyperref, lists, enumitem, description

This question is related to [Reference name of description list item in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex), because that is the same as what I am doing. The answer provided there works in most cases, but I found a case where it fails to label a macro properly.

## Description of Problem

The normal behavior of labels is to reference last labelable thing (`\autoref{}` in place of `\ref{}` will verify this in some cases). This is not the desired effect when labeling the default item labels themselves in description lists with labels (***note*:** terminology conflict…labels of items `\item [label] Text.` and labeling the item labels `\item [label\label{mylabel}] Text.`*). Therefore, we need to redefine items for description lists. The question mentioned above does this.

When using labels within description lists, a `\phantomsection` needs to be added for the labels to label :). Makes sense so far to me. I'd like to know why the code fails below *(see notes in code)*.

## Purpose

I am describing many lists of parameters and oftentimes, the parameters for one function have already been described elsewhere. Cross-references are then extremely convenient.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % xelatex ext font support
\usepackage{enumitem} % Add easy custom list support
\usepackage{menukeys} % Demonstrate labeling of macros
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add ref support
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Globally set indentation for new paragraphs
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % my custom macro

\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Labels}
\label{mymacro} %<-- This works (comment this out when testing my problem)
\begin{description}
\item [Fruit] The is a fruit. A plain item.
\item [\menu{Vegetables}\label{menukeysmacro}] This is a vegetable. Macro from the \texttt{menukeys} package.
%\item [\mymacro{Meat}\label{mymacro}] This is some meat. Custom macro. % <-- This does not work (This should label \mymacro{Meat})
\end{description}

\section{References}    
This is a menukeysmacro \ref{menukeysmacro} for fun. 

Now we reference the mymacro \ref{mymacro}.
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

## Problematic Code (just code above with the appropriate things uncommented)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % xelatex ext font support
\usepackage{enumitem} % Add easy custom list support
\usepackage{menukeys} % Demonstrate labeling of macros
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add ref support
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Globally set indentation for new paragraphs
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % my custom macro

\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Labels}
\begin{description}
\item [Fruit] The is a fruit. A plain item.
\item [\menu{Vegetables}\label{menukeysmacro}] This is a vegetable. Macro from the \texttt{menukeys} package.
\item [\mymacro{Meat}\label{mymacro}] This is some meat. Custom macro. % <-- This does not work (This should label \mymacro{Meat})
\end{description}

\section{References}    
This is a menukeysmacro \ref{menukeysmacro} for fun. 

Now we reference the mymacro \ref{mymacro}.
\end{document}
```

Update: This question has some follow-up question to be found here: [How can I use hyperref hyperlinks inside of description list keys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297123/how-can-i-use-hyperref-hyperlinks-inside-of-description-list-keys)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok. I adjusted the question. I hope it is clear. See code comment updates too.

Comment: No, sorry. Should the `mymacro` label refer to Fruit???

Comment: Your statement about "labels refering to the last section" is wrong. When you place a `\label`, it refers to the last thing that was said to be "labelable".

Comment: @yo' Thanks for catching that slip, I will fix that immediately.

Comment: @macmadness86: The `\label` command uses the last counter being used in `refstepcounter`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's only one way to do it.

Comment: @macmadness86 I still fail to see what's wrong. `menukeysmacro` is `Vegetables` and `mymacro` is `section 1`. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @yo': You could do it by hand of course too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\edef\@currentlabel{#1}` must be replaced by `\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}` otherwise the expansion of the argument fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % xelatex ext font support
\usepackage{enumitem} % Add easy custom list support
\usepackage{menukeys} % Demonstrate labeling of macros
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add ref support
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Globally set indentation for new paragraphs
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % my custom macro

\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Labels}
%\label{mymacro} %<-- This works (creates reference to Label)
\begin{description}
\item [\menu{Fruit}] The is a fruit. A plain item.
\item [\menu{Vegetables}\label{menukey::Vegetables}] This is a vegetable. Macro from the \texttt{menukeys} package.
\item [\mymacro{Meat}\label{mymacro}] This is some meat. Custom macro. % <-- This does not work (comment out other mymacro label)
\end{description}

\section{References}    
This is a menukeysmacro \ref{menukey::Vegetables} for fun. 

Now we reference the mymacro \ref{mymacro}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

The real culprit is that `\texttt` as most (or all?) `\text...` style macros are (highly) fragile.

An alternative (without using `\protected@edef`) would be to make the `\texttt{}` command robust (Package `etoolbox` is needed for this)

```
\robustify\texttt
```

But this procedure will become tedious if other fragile commands will appear in `\mymacro`. So `\protected@edef` is perhaps the better way.

Comment: Now you know why the original question title contained the word "robust" :) Thanks. I thought there was some trick to make it self-protecting as explained: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands

Comment: Could you please explain why the expansion of the argument for the `\menu{}` macro works, but not for the `\texttt{}` macro?

Comment: @macmadness86: sorry, I was in lectures and could not answer immediately. I assume, that `\texttt{...}` is the usual culprit, i.e. it's fragile