# How can I use hyperref hyperlinks inside of description list keys?

Tags: hyperref, lists, enumitem, description

I already asked a related question, [How can I label / reference description items that contain macros by name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268842/how-can-i-label-reference-description-items-that-contain-macros-by-name)

Now I am having difficulty compiling description lists using `hyperref`'s hyperlinks.

## Problem

I'd like to make description list items (let's call each item a *key-value pair*) that contains hyperlinks in its keys.

## Code

The description list has already been redefined once to allow label references to macros (namely the macros provided by `menukeys`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for xelatex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List
    
\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{User Interface}
The following is a list of important user interface components:
\begin{description}
  \item [Main Window] The main window. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Side Bar] for navigation. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Document Tree] A document tree. % <-- Not so cool.
  %\item [\hyperlink{gui:mainwindow}{Main Window}] The main window. % <-- way cooler
  %\item [\hyperlink{gui:sidebar}{Side Bar}] for navigation. % <-- way cooler
  %\item [\hyperlink{gui:documenttree}{Document Tree}] A document tree. % <-- way cooler
\end{description}

\hypertarget{gui:mainwindow}{\subsection{Main Window}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:sidebar}{\subsection{Side Bar}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:documenttree}{\subsection{Document Tree}}
Some nice long description.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect\hyperlink`, but this has to be done each time :-(, unless `robustified` or a (weird) redefinition of `\item`

Comment: I wrapped the `\hyperlink`s in curly braces and it worked... 
(XeTeX 2.6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\item` is a command with moving (optional) argument, i.e. `\hyperlink` is fragile here. Either use `\protect\hyperlink{...}` (each time) or incorporate the `\protect into`\item[...]`with a redefinition of`\item`.

Another possibility is to use `\robustify{\hyperlink}` (needs `etoolbox`), but am unsure whether a global *robustification* of `\hyperlink` is a clever idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for xelatex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\origitem\item

\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
  \origitem[\protect#1]%
  }{%
    \origitem% 
  }
}
}

\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{User Interface}
The following is a list of important user interface components:
\begin{description}
  \item [Main Window] The main window. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Side Bar] for navigation. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Document Tree] A document tree. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [\hyperlink{gui:mainwindow}{Main Window}] The main window. % <-- way cooler
  \item [\hyperlink{gui:sidebar}{Side Bar}] for navigation. % <-- way cooler
  \item [\hyperlink{gui:documenttree}{Document Tree}] A document tree. % <-- way cooler
\end{description}

\clearpage

\hypertarget{gui:mainwindow}{\subsection{Main Window}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:sidebar}{\subsection{Side Bar}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:documenttree}{\subsection{Document Tree}}
Some nice long description.

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Even shorter way, with `\deschyperlink` as a robust wrapper command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for xelatex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\DeclareRobustCommand{\deschyperlink}[2]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
}


\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{User Interface}
The following is a list of important user interface components:
\begin{description}
  \item [Main Window] The main window. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Side Bar] for navigation. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [Document Tree] A document tree. % <-- Not so cool.
  \item [\deschyperlink{gui:mainwindow}{Main Window}] The main window. % <-- way cooler
  \item [\deschyperlink{gui:sidebar}{Side Bar}] for navigation. % <-- way cooler
  \item [\deschyperlink{gui:documenttree}{Document Tree}] A document tree. % <-- way cooler
\end{description}

\clearpage

\hypertarget{gui:mainwindow}{\subsection{Main Window}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:sidebar}{\subsection{Side Bar}}
Some nice long description.

\hypertarget{gui:documenttree}{\subsection{Document Tree}}
Some nice long description.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the hasty answer. I don't suppose there is a way to do this without any extra dependencies hmm? (e.g. letltxmacro) (btw I think I have etoolbox as a dependency already).

Comment: @macmadness86: Well, `letltxmacro` isn't necessary here, since `\item` does not really have the optional argument. `\let\origitem\item` works too.

Comment: Another possibility: Define a robust command, say `\myhyperlink` which is a wrapper to `\hyperlink`. This can't break apart then.

Comment: Unrelated: I love the word "robustification"

Comment: @macmadness86: It's an invented word, of course.

Comment: @macmadness86: I've added the 'shortest' possible solution, I think ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrapping the `\hyperref` in curly braces should do the trick.

> @Tom wrote this in a comment, but I (not a TeXpert) think this is a legitimate answer, because it works just as expected. This answer ist just for visibility.