# Referencing custom label with enumitem

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want something as follow:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[(A)] \label{hyp:a} foo 
  \item[(X)] \label{hyp:x} bar
  \item[(G)] \label{hyp:g} foo bar
\end{enumerate}

Now referencing to hypothesis \ref{hyp:a}, \ref{hyp:x} and \ref{hyp:g}.
```

The last line should produce:

> Now referencing to (A), (X) and (G).

For now, it produces:

> Now referencing to , and .

---

I used random letters A, X and G so that you understand that a enumerated `\alph*` list is not what I want.

(Also, if it has any importance, I actually want that the list with custom label inside an item of another normally enumerated list.)

Comment: The `\item[foo]` does not set `\@currentlabel` so there is nothing to reference there

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365322/label-reference-description-items-with-enumitem

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Perfect, that is exactly it.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks, but the answer is way more to cumbersome for what I want. I have only one list that I want to do this on, so I'll just change `\@currentlabel` by hand on those item instead of redefining the behaviour of `\item`.

Comment: Nice... Glad that you found your way... (Not deleting the comment because it may help other users)... I think there was an answer here that deleted (not sure) and was using `\href`... It is an option too if you do manual all the work needed

Comment: @koleygr Of course keep the comment. I'm not sure why the answer was deleted, but I does not suits me anyway : I want the referencing to use the usual `\ref` command (it is a collaboratively written document and I'm ok with tweaking the definition of the labels but other users shouldn't have to know it just to cross reference those labels).

Comment: Nice... You can add and accept your own answer when finish. This way you will help other people too.

Answer (score 8):

`\item[foo]\label{foo}` will not place a correct label, neither for the reference itself nor the linking if `hyperref` is used, since no counter is involved with the `\item[]` version of `\item`.

A possible solution is define an explicit `\@currentlabel`, then apply `\label`, thereby faking the usage of some counter.

The package `crossreftools` provides `\crtcrossreflabel` for such occurences. The optional value is the label name. However, since `\item[...]` is used, `{\crtcrossreflabel{}[]}` has to be applied in order to protect the `[]`. The correct hyper anchor is ensured with `\phantomsection` inside already.

I've provided a simple `inline` method with `\optionaldesc` with `\phantomsection` which basically the same behavior as `\crtcrossreflabel`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\optionaldesc}[2]{%
  \phantomsection
  #1\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\section{Foo} 
\clearpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item[{\crtcrossreflabel{(A)}[hyp:a]}] foo 
\item[\optionaldesc{(X)}{hyp:x}] bar
\item[{\crtcrossreflabel{(G)}[hyp:g]}] foo bar
\end{enumerate}
\clearpage
Now referencing to hypothesis \ref{hyp:a}, \ref{hyp:x}
and \ref{hyp:g}
\end{document}
```

[image]