# Remove last character from decription label in cross reference label

Tags: cross-referencing, description

I read how to make a reference that has as a label the label of a description label ([Reference name of description list item in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex/1248#1248)):

```
\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

This works. However, often description labels end with a special character, like `:` or `,`, which should not be part of the reference label. How can I remove this character from the reference label?

**Edit:**

Tried:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
...
  \edef\@currentlabel{\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}}%
...
```

But that seems not to work for some reason.

**Edit**

Here is a full document (from the link above):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Vehicle\label{itm:vehicle}] Something
    \item [Bus\label{itm:bus}] A type of \ref{itm:vehicle}
    \item [Car\label{itm:car}] A type of \ref{itm:vehicle} smaller than a    \ref{itm:bus}
\end{description} 

The item `\ref{itm:bus}' is listed on page~\pageref{itm:bus} in section~\nameref{itm:bus}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If one knows already what kind of symbol follows a description label one can leave it out of the description label an add it static to the definition, like `\orgdescriptionlabel{#1:}` or `\orgdescriptionlabel{#1,}`.

Comment: I would be very nice if you would provide a document to start with, not just fragments

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping that the provided link was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select to remove a final punctuation based on `\spacefactor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\daniel@currentlabel{#1}%
  \sbox\z@{\daniel@currentlabel\xdef\daniel@sf{\the\spacefactor}}%
  \ifnum\daniel@sf>1000
    \noexpandarg
    \expandafter\StrGobbleRight\expandafter{\daniel@currentlabel}{1}[\daniel@currentlabel]%
  \fi
  \def\x{%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentlabelname
    \expandafter{\daniel@currentlabel}}%
  \x
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Vehicle\label{itm:vehicle}] Something
    \item [Bus,\label{itm:bus}] A type of \nameref{itm:vehicle}
    \item [Car\label{itm:car}] A type of \nameref{itm:vehicle} smaller than a \nameref{itm:bus}
\end{description}

References: `\nameref{itm:bus}' and `\nameref{itm:car}'.
\end{document}
```

After a punctuation sign, the space factor is greater than 1000 (with standard `\nonfrenchspacing` setup; if you use `\frenchspacing`, also load `amsthm` that adjusts things so the space factor can still be used).

[image]

In order to use `\ref` instead of `\nameref`, just a small change is needed; I would recommend being consistent in using `\ref` for numbers and `\nameref` for text, but I can understand the need of not changing existing documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\daniel@currentlabel{#1}%
  \sbox\z@{\daniel@currentlabel\xdef\daniel@sf{\the\spacefactor}}%
  \ifnum\daniel@sf>1000
    \noexpandarg
    \expandafter\StrGobbleRight\expandafter{\daniel@currentlabel}{1}[\daniel@currentlabel]%
  \fi
  \def\x{%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentlabel
    \expandafter{\daniel@currentlabel}}%
  \x
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Vehicle\label{itm:vehicle}] Something
    \item [Bus,\label{itm:bus}] A type of \ref{itm:vehicle}
    \item [Car\label{itm:car}] A type of \ref{itm:vehicle} smaller than a \ref{itm:bus}
\end{description}

References: `\ref{itm:bus}' and `\ref{itm:car}'.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds very good. But for some reason I get only references to section numbers.

Comment: @Daniel What did you expect? No number is generated in a description.

Comment: I was seeing only section numbers instead of the labels. But that was due to some other setting I had in my file. Works perfect!

Comment: You changed the original code so that instead of `\ref` the `\nameref`has to be used. Could you tell me what I would have to change in order to have `\ref` changed instead?

Comment: @Daniel It's a matter of consistency: `\ref` is about numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. Unfortunately, I cannot change whether `\ref` or `\nameref` command is used for these references at the moment. Could you tell me what I would have to change?

Comment: @Daniel Added the change

Comment: Thanks. Btw. what is all this "daniel" in the code good for? :)

Comment: @Daniel An “arbitrary” prefix that emulates a namespace, so not to inadvertently clobber existing commands.