# Why am I having a space to the next word? How to fix it?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem, description

I have what I would like to think, a simple question.

I have the following tex code:

```
\begin{description}%[style=nextline]
\item [Category\label{desc:category}] blablabla
\item [Profile\label{desc:profile}] blabla (\nameref{desc:category}) blabla.
\end{description}
```

The result is something like this:

**Category** blablabla

**Profile** blabla (Category   'bunch of spaces') blabla.

Why do I have these spaces after Category reference I made?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us how, i.e., with which options and in which order, you load the `hyperref` and/or `nameref` packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My guess is that the redefinition of `\label` or of `\nameref` introduces spurious spaces because the lines of the definition are not properly terminated with `%`. But we can only tell for sure if you provide a *complete* small document showing everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Reference name of `description` list item in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1230/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replicate the issue you're reporting, it turns out to be necessary to load the `enumitem` package in addition to the `hyperref` (or `nameref`) package. E.g., the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % or: \usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Category\label{desc:category}] blablabla
\item[Profile\label{desc:profile}] blabla 
   (\nameref{desc:category}) blabla
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

In short, it looks like you've come across a rather significant and quite unfortunate conflict between the `enumitem` and `hyperref` packages. ([Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365583/5001), which was posted a couple of minutes earlier than mine, provides a more in-depth diagnosis of the nature of the conflict conflict.) Interestingly, the three answers to the query [Reference name of description list item in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365567/5001) do not appear to fix the spacing issue.

Instead of using the `enumitem` package, you might consider using the [enumerate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) package. It doesn't offer quite as many bells and whistles as the `enumitem` package does. However, depending on your formatting needs (about which you've revealed exactly zero so far...), the `enumerate` package may offer all the functionality you really need.

---

If, however, you simply *must* use the `enumitem` package, I suggest you *not* employ the basic-LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` mechanism inside `description` environments. Instead, use the more general `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` mechanism of the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\hypertarget{desc:category}{Category}] blablabla
\item[\hypertarget{desc:profile}{Profile}] blabla 
   (\hyperlink{desc:category}{Category}) blabla
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was using enumitem as you guys said. Lesson learned. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the O.P. is using `enumitem` (hint: `style=nextline`)

`enumitem` adds a `\hfil` in the `\descriptionlabel` macro, so the label would be `Category\hfil`, leaving a large space to the right.

The `description` environment of the standard classes (better: LaTeX core) does not have this is undesireful feature.

The idea is to `\let\hfil\relax` in the `\@currentlabelname` macro, which is the name that is stored for `\nameref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Add easy custom list support
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add ref support
%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Globally set indentation for new paragraphs
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=30pt,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax} % Global Setup Description List

\makeatletter % Redefinition of Description List Items source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1248/13552
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \let\orglabel\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
  \edef\@currentlabelname{\let\hfil\relax #1}%
  \let\label\orglabel
  \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [Category\label{desc:category}] blablabla
\item [Profile\label{desc:profile}] blabla (\nameref{desc:category}) blabla.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `.aux` file, you see

```
\newlabel{desc:category}{{}{1}{\enit@align {\enit@format {Category\label {desc:category}}}}{Doc-Start}{}}
\newlabel{desc:profile}{{}{1}{\enit@align {\enit@format {Profile\label {desc:profile}}}}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

and we want to get rid of `\enit@align` and `\enit@format`; this can be done by loading the `gettitlestring` package with the `expand` option and disabling the two unwanted commands by making them simply deliver their argument. This redefinition is only temporary, when `nameref` macros are gathering the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Add easy custom list support
\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add ref support
\setlist[description]{% Global Setup Description List
  labelwidth=0pt,
  leftmargin=30pt,
  itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax
}

\makeatletter
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
  \let\enit@align\@firstofone
  \let\enit@format\@firstofone
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [Category\label{desc:category}] blablabla
\item [Profile\label{desc:profile}] blabla (\nameref{desc:category}) blabla.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Now the `.aux` file has

```
\newlabel{desc:category}{{}{1}{Category}{Doc-Start}{}}
\newlabel{desc:profile}{{}{1}{Profile}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

and the output is as expected.

[image]