# Labelling a section or "subproof" within a proof

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, theorems, proof-package

Does anyone have ideas on labelling a section in a proof that can be referenced later?

Just to be clear I would like to do a "subproof" in a proof environment.

Comment: The name "section" is already used, as is "part".  Easiest is to use an enumerate environment.  (The counter name is enumi, but you can call it whatever you want.)

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, based upon the cited answer on tex.stackexchange.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{pfparts}{description}{1}
\setlist[pfparts,1]{%
  font=\normalfont\textsf,
  itemindent=2pt,
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
  labelsep=0.75ex
}
% From 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
  $2^{n} > n$ for every natural number $n$.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}

\begin{pfparts}
  \item[\namedlabel{pfpart:base}{Base step}.]
    First, $2^{0} = 1 > 0$.

  \item[\namedlabel{pfpart:induct}{Inductive step}.]
    We wish to prove that, for every natural number $n$, if $2^{n} > n$, then $2^{n+1}>n+1$. 
    Let $n$ be an arbitrary natural number. Assume that $2^{n} > n$. Then
    \[
      2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n} > 2 \cdot n = n + n \geq n,
    \]
    and so $2^{n+1} > n$. \qedhere
\end{pfparts}

\end{proof}

In \ref{pfpart:base} we used \dots.

\end{document}
```

[image: Proof parts referenced by name]