# \hyperref pointing to top of section rather than correct item

Tags: hyperref

I've got \hyperrefs mostly working, but references to one section — I've noticed two of them so far — insist on taking me to the top of the \section rather than to the desired item below.  The source paragraph looks like this:

`\section{The Cert workbook:} The Cert workbooks created by the HomeOffice program have the filename “\tit{RunLabel} \tit{manager’s AD ID}.xlsx”, where the \tit{RunLabel} is a string you designate in \hyperref[setRunLabel]{the RunLabel Setting}.  Each in-house Cert contains four or five worksheets....`

The target area looks like this:

`\item[RunLabel:]\label{setRunLabel} The Cert workbooks are created in a folder designated by....`

Since most \hyperref links work properly, but the ones pointing to items in this particular section point to the top of the section rather than to the specific item, I suspect I've done something wrong in setting up the chapter or section.  But I don't see any problem.  Maybe you will:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Settings in Cert.xlsm}\label{AppSettings}
In Cert.xlsm is a worksheet named Settings....

\section{Description of the Settings worksheet:}
The Settings can be listed....

\section{How Settings work:}
Settings have different values depending....

\section{Description of the individual settings (in alphabetical order):}

\begin{description}[itemindent=-5mm]
\item[ADCooked:]\label{setADCooked} The path and filename of the processed (“cooked”) AD file....
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: description lists have no anchor, use \phantomsection\label{...}.

Comment: Weird!  I didn't see that coming, but it works.  Thanks.

Comment: With `\hyperref` you can use `\hypertarget` instead of `\label`, no `\refstepcounter` needed.

Comment: Maybe also useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex

Answer (score 4):

hyperlinks jump to a target, an anchor. Such targets are typically created when something is numbered, so e.g. `\section` has an anchor, and enumerate lists too.
If you set a `\label` a reference to this label will jump to the most recently created target.

So e.g. here the `\pageref` will not jump to page 2  but to the section on page 1 (as would a `\ref`) as there is the most recent anchor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{a section}

\newpage 
HERE\label{here}?

\newpage 
Jump to page \pageref{here}??
\end{document}
```

If you want a reference to jump to a place which has no automatically created target, you can create an anchor with `\phantomsection`, or in a recent LaTeX with `\MakeLinkTarget`. The second command is also defined if hyperref is removed from the document and it can also be used as a replacement for `\hypertarget`. It is documented in `hyperref-linktarget.pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{a section}

\newpage 
HERE\MakeLinkTarget{}\label{here}?

\newpage 
Jump: \pageref{here}?
\end{document}
```