Hyperref with manyfoot generating links for footnotes that lead to top of section rather than to footnotes
I'm using manyfoot and hyperref, and I have three groups of footnotes: default footnotes with Arabic numerals, and two other groups of footnotes with lowercase and capital Roman numerals. The hyperref links to the Arabic and lowercase Roman footnotes that I place using \ref in various places in the document work fine, but the links to the capital Roman footnotes lead to the top of the section that those footnotes are in, not to the footnotes themselves.
MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatother
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[Roman]
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\manyfoottarget{\makebox[0pt][r]{\hypertarget{Hfootnote.\theHfootnote}\quad}}
\patchcmd\MFL@fnoteplain{\rule}{\manyfoottarget\rule}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fist Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
Some text\footnote{Regular Arabic footnote \label{fn:1}}
Some more text\footnoteA{Lowercase Roman footnote \label{fn:i}}
Some more text\footnoteB{Uppercase Roman footnote \label{fn:I}}
Some more text\footnoteB{Uppercase Roman footnote \label{fn:II}}
\section{Third Section}
Some text\footnote{see footnote \ref{fn:1} above}
Some more text\footnoteA{See footnote \ref{fn:i} above}
Some more text \footnoteB{See footnotes \ref{fn:I} and \ref{fn:II} above}.
\end{document}

The first two \ref commands work fine, but the second two generate links that lead to the top of section 2.

Just a try, place \usepackage{hyperref} at the last, i.e., just before the \begin{document}

MadyYuvi I tried that, it doesn't help.

You didn't test your document. A MWE is not some deco to make the question look better, it is something that we want to use to test your issue.  So ensure that it is usable.

This is answered at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671898/hyperref-pointing-to-top-of-section-rather-than-correct-item?rq=1.
