# Error when combining glossaries and label of description item

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, description

I want to use the glossaries package and I want to be able to reference descritpion list items by their name.
For the latter problem, I found a solution ([Reference name of description list item in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) , the accepted answer). This works fine.
It is also no problem to incorporate glossary-entries into the text, however when printing the list of glossaries, this leads to an error.

My solution by now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%
% Macro for description
\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \let\orglabel\label
    \let\label\@gobble
    \phantomsection
    \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
    %\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    \let\label\orglabel
    \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[toc,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{KG}{KG}{Knowledge Graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[(A1)\label{desc:A1}] Test
\end{description}
As can be seen in \ref{desc:A1} a \gls{KG} is...
    
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    
\end{document}
```

This works when either commenting out \printglossary[type=\acronymtype] or everything between makeatletter and makeatother.

The error message is:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\gls@start@measuring ...else \let \gls@org@target 
                                                  \glstarget \let \gls@org@l...

l.5         \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}
```

As I am not an expert on Latex, I would appreciate any help.
I am open for all solutions enabling to achieve a combination of labels on items and the glossaries, they need not to be based on this code.

Comment: Doesn't glossaries by default use the description list to typeset its lists. Thus it does not like your redefinitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restore the original definition of `descriptionlabel` before `\printglossary`.

Meanwhile, I provided better code than yours for suppressing the `\label` inside the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,automake]{glossaries}

%%%
% Macro for description
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy{\orgdescriptionlabel}{\descriptionlabel}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \phantomsection
    \begingroup\let\label\@gobble\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\@currentlabel{#1}%
      \def\noexpand\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    }\x
    \orgdescriptionlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{KG}{KG}{Knowledge Graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[(A1)\label{desc:A1}] Test
\end{description}
As can be seen in \ref{desc:A1} a \gls{KG} is...

\RenewCommandCopy{\descriptionlabel}{\orgdescriptionlabel}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\NewCommandCopy` and `\RenewCommandCopy` that are a lot safer than `\let` (you need a fairly recent version of LaTeX). Also `\protected@edef` is better than `\edef`.

[image]